# How do I store the qrcode generated using phpqrcode into a db instead of in a filepath?

Tags: php, qr-code

I need to store the qrcode (generated using phpqrcode) into a db instead of placing them in a filepath.
The examples given in the sourceforge project (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/) speaks only about storing them in a physical file path. I dont want to store them in a file path.
Please advice.

```
QRcode::png($codecontent, $filepath);
```

Comment: Store `$codecontent` to your database and then when you need to generate the QRCode, retrieve it and run that command

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. That does sound like a solution, but the qr image will still be stored in a filepath which I dont want to.I would keep that as a last option.

Comment: You don't want to store PNG on disk, you are not outputting it to the browser - what exactly do you want to store in the database?

Comment: I want to store the qrcode in the database and will be retrieved when a business card of the user is printed, it might also be emailed to the user.

Comment: As what? As a PNG stream? That seems suboptimal. It would be actually better to store the _path_ to the image on disk. Alternatively, generate the QR code on demand as Aaron suggested. Alternatively again - phpqrcode has a method to generate the code as ASCII art, if you're very hard-pressed to put a QR code in a DB, that might be the way to go... it certainly is better than storing a blob of actual _image_.

Comment: Thanks @PawelJ.Wal, how to generate the code as ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments with the OP, and the question as precised - how to generate the QR code as ASCII - this topic is covered in the examples for phpqrcode:

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=702

```
$codeContents = '12345'; // what to store

// generates the contents as array
// elements of array contain lines of the QR code
// lines are comprised of ones and zeros
$text = QRcode::text($codeContents);

// here array is joined, putting <br/> at end of lines
// for HTML display
$raw = join("<br/>", $text); 

// 1s and 0s are converted to "blocky" characters
// so that display is more like QR code and less like stream of 101010
$raw = strtr($raw, array( 
    '0' => '<span style="color:white">&#9608;&#9608;</span>', 
    '1' => '&#9608;&#9608;' 
));
```

After these steps, an ASCII art representation of the code is stored in `$raw`; you *could* store that in a database, show to a client, or send over e-mail.

If you do send it in an e-mail, I'd suggest replacing `<br/>` with `\n` and ensuring that the email's encoding is set to UTF-8 so that the characters show up properly.